# Undefined reference to runner in pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, vi

I am trying to use threads for Collatz Conjecture which states if a number is even it is divided by 2 but if the number is odd then the number is multiplied by 3 then added by one. Eventually, the number will equal zero. I am using Linux and VI and C. My problem is I keep getting an undefined reference to runner in main function error. My code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int num;
void *runner(void *);
struct pt{
long num[100];
int size;
}shared;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
pthread_t tid;
pthread_attr_t attr;

struct pt *shared_info = &shared;

if(argc != 2) {
 fprintf(stderr, "usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
    return -1;
}
if(atoi(argv[1]) <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%d must be > 0\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    return -2;
}

shared_info -> size = atoi(argv[1]);
pthread_attr_init(&attr);
pthread_create(&tid, &attr, runner, (void *)shared_info);
pthread_join (tid,NULL);

int i;
for(i = 0; i < (*shared_info).size - 1; i++)
    printf("%ld,",(*shared_info).num[i]);
printf("%d\n", (*shared_info).num[(*shared_info).size - 1]);
return 0;

void *runner(void *param) {
    struct pt * shared_info = (struct pt*) param;
    int x = shared_info -> size;
    int i = 0;

    while((shared_info -> num[i-1]) != 1) {
        if(x % 2 ==0) {
            x /= 2;
        }
        else {
            x = x * 3 + 1;

        }
    }
    shared_info -> size = i;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missplaced a "}", you have to move one of those at the end to after "return 0;"

And also you're loop will be infinite because you have it going until "1" when it should be until "0".

Comment: You are correct. I needed another set of eyes it appears.